# Время жизни переменных захватываемых по ссылке

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
//#include <Windows.h>
#include <mutex>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::mutex g_mutex;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct _Int
{
    _Int() { std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }
    _Int(const _Int&) { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    _Int(_Int&&) = delete;
    ~_Int() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }

    int m_i { 42 };
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void _print(_Int i)
{
    std::cout << i.m_i << std::endl;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void worker2(void* param)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    std::cout << "worker 2" << std::endl;

     std::function<void(void)>* lambda = (std::function<void(void)>*)param;
     (*lambda)();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void worker()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    std::cout << "worker 1" << std::endl;

    _Int y;

    std::function<void(void)>* lambda = new std::function<void(void)>{[=]() { _print(y); }};

    std::thread thread(worker2, lambda);
    thread.detach(); 
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    std::thread _thread(worker);
    _thread.detach();

    system("pause");
}
```

Вывод:

```
worker 1
constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
destructor
destructor
worker 2
copy constructor
42
destructor
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

**Вопрос:** В выводе мы видим 4 конструктора и всего 3 деструктора, куда делся 4-й?
Также почему конструктор копии вызывается дважды?

Пример вывода для захвата по ссылке:

```
worker 1
constructor
destructor
worker 2
copy constructor
42
destructor
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Код с захватом по ссылке невалидный, но баланс конструкторов соблюдён.

Буду благодарен за ссылку на чтиво, где развернуто описывается время жизни переменных в лямбдах, потоках, с захватом по значению и ссылке

P.S. new без delete сделан специально, чтобы объект lambda был живой после завершения работы потока worker()

Comment: Если коротко, то захват переменных в лямбду по ссылке на время жизни переменных никак не влияет. Ну а еще для `new std::function` нет `delete`. И странно видеть такую дикую смесь С++ и WinAPI. Если уж используется `std::function` и `std::mutex`, то отчего не взять `std::thread`?

Comment: @VTT, да это видно по второму выводу, а по конструкторам поможете понять что происходит?

Comment: @VTT, new без delete сделан намерено, чтобы std::function жил после завершения потока worker. винапи убрал.

Comment: *"new без delete сделан намерено"* - ну а смысл тогда спрашивать куда делся 4 деструктор? Сделайте нормальный join у каждого потока, удалите все объекты, и тогда можно будет о чем-то рассуждать.

Comment: @VTT, вы как всегда правы) если добавить delete во второй поток, то деструкторы в порядке. Спасибо